# Change Class of List Object on Button Press

Tags: vue.js

When I click on a Button I want the class of my List Object to change.
Do you have any examples of how im able to do that?

Comment: Can you provide an example or show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Click an item to toggle a class... you should be able to follow this format.

https://jsfiddle.net/t716o85k/

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <p @click="toggle($event)"> {{ item.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{ name: "Item1", id: "1" }, { name: "Item2", id: "2" }, { name: "Item3", id: "3" }]
  },
    methods: {
    toggle($event){
        let s = $event.target.classList;
      s.contains("my-class") ? s.remove("my-class") : s.add("my-class");
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.my-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: and is it possible to do the same with a subpage? Im making this projectbar for an Webapp, and there are three steps the User has to complete to get what he wants. And now I wanted to know if I could do the same thing with links
I mean that if the User is on this page Step 1 is Complete

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but I would need more code to elaborate on. The easy way would be to use an existing `wizard` since it sounds like that's what you're after. [Here is an existing Wizard component you can use](https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/) - and [here are some demos](https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/?id=simple) of it in use.